# How to show data values in top of bar chart and line chart in chart.js 3

Tags: javascript, chart.js, bar-chart, linechart, vue-chartjs

I would like to know if it's possible to show the chart data in chartjs3. I know there is such a thing for Chartjs2 but i dont know if its possible in 3

Comment: what do you mean by "chart data" ? can you show example of what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image: data values on chart]

If that's your requirement.

You might want to use [chartjs-plugin-datalabels](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels) plugin. It works with vue-chartjs.

```
import Chart from 'chart.js'
import { Line } from 'vue-chartjs'
import ChartJsPluginDataLabels from 'chartjs-plugin-datalabels'
```

Incase you don't want the plugin globally.

`Chart.defaults.global.plugins.datalabels.display = false;`

You can find the documentation for adding a plugin https://vue-chartjs.org/api/#addplugin.